# How to apply function on mutlple-index pandas dataframe elegantly like on panel?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like:

```
ticker        MS                AAPL          
field      price    volume     price    volume
0      -0.861210 -0.319607 -0.855145  0.635594
1      -1.986693 -0.526885 -1.765813  1.696533
2      -0.154544 -1.152361 -1.391477 -2.016119
3       0.621641 -0.109499  0.143788 -0.050672
```

generated from following codes, please ignore the numbers which are just as examples

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('MS', 'price'), ('MS', 'volume'), ('AAPL', 'price'), ('AAPL', 'volume')], names=['ticker', 'field'])
data = np.random.randn(4, 4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Now, I would like to calculate pct_change() or any function user definded on each price column, and add a new column on 'field' level to store the result.

I know how to do it elegantly if the data is a Panel, which is deprecated since ver 0.20. Suppose panel's 3 axis are date, ticker and field:

```
p[:,:, 'ret'] = p[:,:,'price'].pct_change()
```

That's all. But I have not found a similar elegant way to do it with multiple index dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `IndexSlice`

```
df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'price']].apply(pd.Series.pct_change).rename(columns={'price':'ret'})
Out[1181]: 
ticker        MS      AAPL
field        ret       ret
0            NaN       NaN
1      -1.420166 -0.279805
2       3.011155  0.062529
3      -1.609004  0.759954
```

Comment: I am getting `KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
`

Answer (score 0):

```
def cstm(s):
  return s.pct_change()

new = pd.concat(
    [df.xs('price', 1, 1).apply(cstm)],
    axis=1, keys=['new']
).swaplevel(0, 1, 1)

df.join(new).sort_index(1)

ticker      AAPL                            MS                    
field        new     price    volume       new     price    volume
0            NaN -0.855145  0.635594       NaN -0.861210 -0.319607
1       1.064928 -1.765813  1.696533  1.306863 -1.986693 -0.526885
2      -0.211991 -1.391477 -2.016119 -0.922211 -0.154544 -1.152361
3      -1.103335  0.143788 -0.050672 -5.022430  0.621641 -0.109499
```

Or

```
def cstm(s):
  return s.pct_change()

df.stack(0).assign(
    new=lambda d: d.groupby('ticker').price.apply(cstm)
).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1)
```